# How to get Column names from a csv file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to extract column names from a CVS just by using shell scripting commands?

I have a csv file like this:

```
Name,Age,ID
----------
kart,24,11
----------
carl,18,45
```

This is the code to read from csv file.,

```
head -1 `example.csv`

while IFS=',' read f1 f2 f3

if [[ ${#f3} -le 3 ]]
then
...
...
```

This should work fine, if my csv file have same set of columns in same order, but the coulmns might not be in same order.

Comment: I've removed some useless infomation from your question, but you still have to improve the question. your example code is not even usable. Please, give a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply this?

```sh
head -1 inputfile
```

If you need them in a Bash array, then you can do

```sh
IFS=',' read -a var < inputfile
```

And test the result by

```sh
echo ${var[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
{
    IFS=, read -ra header
    while IFS=, read -ra row; do
        if [ "${row##*(-)}" ]; then
            for ((i=0; i<${#header[@]}; i++)) ;do
                echo -n ${header[i]}:=${row[i]}\ 
            done
            echo
        fi
    done
} < example.csv
```

will render:

```
Name:=kart ID:=11 Age:=24 
Name:=carl ID:=45 Age:=18
```

for sample!

### More complex sample using **associative arrays** and sorting fields

```
declare -A Values='()' 
sortedFields=()
{ 
    IFS=, read -ra header
    for i in ${header[@]} ;do
        printf -v iNum %-9s $i
        sortedFields[64#${iNum// /0}]=$i
    done
    printf -v fread 'Values[%s] ' ${header[@]}
    while IFS=, read -r $fread; do
        lineOut=()
        if [ "${Values[$header]##*(-)}" ]; then
            for i in ${sortedFields[@]}; do
                echo -n $i:=${Values[$i]}' '
            done
            echo
        fi
    done
} < example.csv
```

Must give:

```
Age:=24 ID:=11 Name:=kart 
Age:=18 ID:=45 Name:=carl
```

Or even:

```
declare -A Values='()' 
sortedFields=()
{ 
    IFS=, read -ra header
    for i in ${header[@]} ;do
        printf -v iNum %-9s $i
        sortedFields[64#${iNum// /0}]=$i
    done
    sortedHeader=${sortedFields[*]}
    echo ${sortedHeader// /,}
    printf -v fread 'Values[%s] ' ${header[@]}
    while IFS=, read -r $fread; do
        lineOut=()
        if [ "${Values[$header]##*(-)}" ]; then
            echo ${sortedHeader//?/-}
            lineOut=''
            for i in ${sortedFields[@]}; do
                lineOut+=${Values[$i]},
            done
            echo ${lineOut%,}
        fi
    done
} < example.csv
```

To show:

```
Age,ID,Name
-----------
24,11,kart
-----------
18,45,carl
```